# concurrent read and write to same value in database

Tags: database, jdbc, concurrency, dao

I am making a voting application where votes will be registered against each candidate in database, since its online voting procedure, there are chances that many people will vote same person at a time, so I am facing issue of concurrent read and update, same value, how I should handle this condition.so that each votes are registered and delay should be minimum. I am using JDBC and mySQL as database.

Comment: What does your code look like? `update votes set candidate1 = (candidate1 + 1)` ?

Comment: Use diff table to store the candidates and votes. You can add an entry when a person votes. Later you can get the result by joins.

Answer (score 0):

@user3418790 Make sure you're using the InnoDB DB engine on that table.

Use locking in a transaction and store a timestamp or version identifier in the table so you know when a row has changed.

1. Begin transaction.
2. Get the timestamp or version and compare to the value you expect it to be. If changed then fail and have the user deal with it.
3. Update the data.
4. Commit the transaction.

That it.